# How can I prevent the focus on child elements unless parent is focused?

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

How can I prevent the focus on child elements (in an accessible manner) unless the parent is focused?

Some context:

I'm currently building a form builder using bootstrap, that allows you to click and drag columns / panels around.

However, I want to have inputs inside this container, in order to edit properties of the formfields/inputs that will be generated.

I feel like it would be bad UI/UX and too crowded to have the controls directly clickable, so a scheme where the first click on an input in one of these containers selects the container, and the next the input element would be the best compromise, as this will let you select and or drag containers without worrying about accidentally clicking or dragging the inputs around.

Is this an accessible scheme? Will it cause any accessibility issues?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will need to go through the DOM when the parent gets focus and add the `tabindex` attribute to its children, and then remove it from the children when the parent loses focus.

Comment: "I feel like it would be bad UI/UX" tells me that the first step is to prototype the interface and put it in front of people. Your gut may be right, but understanding *why* it is right can be valuable.